# Тестовый сайт сделанный на HTML пустой, хотя когда я вставляю код в онлайн компайлер всё отображается. Плагин open in browser на visual studio code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Изначально по какой-то причине никакие коды c HTML корректно не работают через Visual Studio Code. Я открываю браузер с кодом через плагин open in browser, но ничего не отображается. Проверял путь - всё в порядке, с расширением уж точно все в порядке. Вставляю код в онлайн компайлер и все идеально. А почему ж через плагин в браузере не отображается то?

Comment: Попробуйте расширение [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer)